# Access Google Now launcher

Tags: google-play-store, apk, launcher

Google closed their Google now launcher and all devices shows incompatible on Google play store. But I can find its apk on internet. After installing app it won't show up in my settings for default launcher. Is there any way I can enjoy Google now launcher?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **rooted** device this might help **[Setting Default applications through ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142880/setting-default-applications-through-adb)**
If you still have issues....  You can ask