# Launcher preference not persistent between reboots

Tags: launcher, 8.1-oreo, stock-rom

I recently purchased the [BLU Vivo One Plus 2019](https://bluproducts.com/devices/vivo-one-plus-2019), which runs Android Oreo (8.1). After installing [kiss launcher](https://kisslauncher.com) and setting as my default launcher, I rebooted my device and the launcher reset back to the pre-installed Launcher3. Note that my other default applications remain, for example I also changed the default messaging app to [Signal](https://signal.org).

Are there any workarounds for this? How can I retain my preference for the default launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220149/267529),

```
adb shell cmd package set-home-activity "fr.neamar.kiss/.MainActivity"
```

However, this only works from an external device.