# How to switch default home launcher at macrodroid

Tags: applications, launcher, home-screen-shortcuts, macrodroid, automate

I use several home launcher apps.
At my school, i use system launcher.And at my home or any other cases,i use nova launcher.
And,ther are secret apps that i don't want to show my friend in nova home.
So,i want to swich default launchers automatically at a certain time.
I think i can use macrodroid.But I'don know how.
Are there any shortcut to swich  default launcher in app?
(it's not good idea to touch the app icon to swich to go to nova or another home)
(I don't  want to root if possible)--edited

Comment: If you have root access you can try the command mentioned here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220149/96277

Comment: Im worried about rooting.Please let me show if there is a way to solve it with other app without rooting.